# Sort Array's according to their values and list in to the table

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following array's :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 147
    [1] => hello
    [2] => Asia/Kolkata
    [3] => Upcoming
)


Array
(
    [0] => 148
    [1] => hello world
    [2] => Asia/Karachi
    [3] => Live
)


Array
(
    [0] => 147
    [1] => ABCD
    [2] => Asia/Colombo
    [3] => NA
)
```

The above array's are coming from database expect the last 6th value is coming from API dynamically. I have pushed that value to database array by using array push.

See the code below:

```
function compareArrayItems($a, $b) {
$order = array(
"Live",
"Upcoming",
"NA"
);
$aWeight = array_search($a[9], $order);
$bWeight = array_search($b[9], $order);
if ($aWeight === false || $bWeight === false || $aWeight === $bWeight)
return 0;
return $aWeight < $bWeight ? 1 : - 1;
}                                           

$sArr = array();
while ($kj = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$arrk = get_status_for_hashtag($kj['start_time'], $kj['end_time'], $kj['day'], $kj['timezone']);
array_push($kj, $arrk);
$sArr[] = $kj;
}                       

usort($sArr, "compareArrayItems");
```

Here the status is nothing but the last value that is : upcoming, live, NA. Currently sorting is coming as usual means according to the database but I want to sort this according to the status means last value. I want live should come first, then upcoming 2nd and NA 3rd. Its not possible by using order-by query because status is not coming from database. Its coming from API and I just merge it with database array.

Hope you got my point.

Thanks.

Comment: There are no. of records in database and I am fetching all the records and displaying it in table by iterating it using while loop. And the status is not always same its changing according to the time. For me display is most important. All tags which status are live should come first, upcoming 2nd and NA third.

Comment: To have this sorted, you first need to fetch all rows from the database and combine it with the other data. Only after that you can sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) providing a custom `$cmp_function` comparing `$a[3]` and `$b[3]` values.

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of usage:

```
$arr = array(
    array(147, "hello", "Asia/Kolkata", "Upcoming"),
    array(148, "hello world", "Asia/Karachi", "Live"),
    array(147, "ABCD", "Asia/Colombo", "NA"),
);
print_r($arr);
usort($arr, "compareArrayItems");
print_r($arr);
```

and custom function for sorting array items in order "Live", "Upcoming", "NA":

```
function compareArrayItems($a, $b)
{
    $order = array(
        "Live",
        "Upcoming",
        "NA"
    );
    $aWeight = array_search($a[3], $order);
    $bWeight = array_search($b[3], $order);
    if ($aWeight === false || $bWeight === false || $aWeight === $bWeight)
        return 0;
    return $aWeight > $bWeight ? 1 : - 1;
}
```

For more information on callbacks you can refer to [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: how can I use this function. Can you please explain me?

Comment: You don't need no explanation (you got it in manual), you just need the code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15978268/2261774

Comment: There are no. of records in database and I am fetching all the records and displaying it in table by iterating it using while loop. And the status is not always same its changing according to the time. For me display is most important. All tags which status are live should come first, upcoming 2nd and NA third.

Comment: Updated the comparison function, please check whether I got it right.

Comment: You pass an array combined with rows fetched from database and other rows to usort function just as M8R-1jmw5r mentioned in comment to your question.

Comment: I tried this but order is not coming properly. Its showing upcoming, NA and live

Comment: Strange to me, make sure that `$aWeight` and `$bWeight` are indexes of corresponding statuses of `$a` and `$b` in `$order` array. If they are numeric everything has to work. Searching for values in `$order` array is case sensitive that's why, for example, `live` and `Live` are not the same.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please check code and tell me whats wrong there. Note I am using $a[9] here not $a[3] and iterating the $sArr using foreach loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28126/discussion-between-ezze-and-jka)

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$sort = [];
foreach ($rows as &$row)
{
   $row[] = $sort[] = get_status_for_hashtag($row['timezone']);
}
unset($row);
array_multisort($sort, $rows);
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/16154)